# ML model prediction using pandas - what is the best approach to drop columns for 'X' and 'y'?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am an amateur coder. I am seeking to understand the difference between :

```
X = np.array(df.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(df[predict])
```

and just the regular code I have previously used in ML models

```
X= data.drop(columns=[predict])
y=data[predict]
```

I am trying to predict the grades of students and the code I am following at the end uses the belowto have the predictions, then original attributes, and the actual score:

```
for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[x], x_test[x], y_test[x])
```

but this appears to only work when the first set of code is used to drop the column as opposed to the second as I get a `KeyError` = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain

```
X = np.array(df.drop([predict], 1)) 
y = np.array(df[predict])
```

In the first line, it drops the `predict` column from dataframe `df` and then the remaining dataframe is converted to a numpy array and assigned to variable `X`. Similarly the `predict` column of `df` is selected and converted to numpy array and assigned to variable `y`.

Now lets look at the scoring code:

```
for x in range(len(predictions)): 
  print(predictions[x], x_test[x], y_test[x])
```

This is trying to print elements of three numpy arrays which I presume are obtained from the earlier `X` and `y` numpy arrays. In the loop  `x` is used to index all the three numpy arrays. As the code is written in a way to index and fetch each element, we need `X` and `y`in numpy array format.

Let us look at the second code:

```
X = data.drop(columns=[predict]) 
y = data[predict]
```

Here `X` is pandas dataframe and `y` is pandas series. Hence we cannot index them the way we index a numpy array and so it does not work.